# Weblogic 12.2 + url rewriting = response blocked

Tags: url-rewriting, weblogic

I have to refresh an old webapp and i'm facing a problem i can't find...

Old situation :
webapp (Java6, wicket) on Weblogic 10.3, external access via URL rewrite by IIS
everything OK

New situation :
refreshed webapp on WL 12.2, IIS unchanged.

Results : Inside URLs : everything OK
Outside URLs : HTTP 200 OK, but all pages HTTP 302 (redirections) fails
browser receive 503 (unavailable) after a while.

I looked at the logs :
WL12 : process OK, response 302 found, location:inside URL
IIS : found code 400

I looked at [Oracle docs][1], i saw that they added CSRF protection, i believed it could be that, i disabled it, but nothing changed.

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance.

[1]: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/wls/WBAPP/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP-GUID-E3A9B2FC-E098-43B1-ACFF-4A457D6062DE  search for "referer-validation"

Answer (score 0):

Forget that.
The WL12 was installed on an "end of life" server running HP Unix.
I deployed the same app on WL12 on redhat, it worked as intended.